# Detail explanation of all states in BottomSheetBehavior Android

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, coordinator-layout, android-bottomsheetdialog

There are around six different states in `BottomSheetBehavior`. I did not get any proper explanation of them.

Like I don't understand difference between `STATE_HIDDEN` and `STATE_COLLAPSED`?

Similarly what is difference between `STATE_SETTLING` and `STATE_DRAGGING`?

Also what is the use of `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED`?

Answer (score 14):

As guided in this article https://androidwave.com/bottom-sheet-behavior-in-android/

The Bottom Sheet mainly have `5 states` -

1. **STATE_COLLAPSED** –  is visible but only showing its peek height. This state is usually the ‘resting position’ of a Bottom Sheet.
2. **STATE_EXPANDED** – The bottom sheet is visible and its maximum height and it is neither dragging or settling.
3. **STATE_DRAGGING** – User is actively dragging the bottom sheet up or down.
4. **STATE_SETTLING** – is settling to a specific height after a drag/swipe gesture.
5. **STATE_HIDDEN** – is no longer visible.

The diference in the `STATE_HIDDEN and STATE_COLLAPSED` is that the when the `BottomSheet` is in the `STATE_HIDDEN` then it is totally hidden i.e. it is not visible on the screen, while when it is in the `STATE_COLLAPSED` then only the peek height is visible.

When the `BottomSheet` is in the `STATE_SETTLING` then it is either expanding or collapsing after a drag or swipe to a specific height, while `STATE_DRAGGING` is the state when when the user is dragging the BottomSheet.

`STATE_HALF_EXPANDED` is the state when the bottom sheet is in the half expanded state.

Comment: Thanks for your description. I got it now.

Answer (score 4):

`STATE_COLLAPSED` -> bottomsheet is ***visible but only showing its peek height***. This state is usually the ‘resting position’ of a Bottom Sheet. The peek height is chosen by the developer and should be enough to indicate there is extra content, allow the user to trigger an action or expand the bottom sheet.

`STATE_HIDDEN` -> bottomsheet is ***no longer visible*** on screen

`STATE_EXPANDED` -> bottom sheet is ***visible and its maximum height*** and it is ***neither dragging or settling***

`STATE_DRAGGING` -> The user is ***actively dragging*** the bottom sheet ***up*** or ***down***.

`STATE_SETTLING` -> bottomsheet is ***settling to specific height*** ***after*** a ***drag/swipe*** gesture. This will be the peek height, expanded height, or 0, in case the user action caused the bottom sheet to hide.

`STATE_HALF_EXPANDED` -> The sheet is ***half-expanded(half visible)***.  (only applicable if behavior_fitToContents has been set to false).

For more information, you can visit [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/)

Comment: Thanks.
I got it and also for the reference.

Comment: No worries;). Happy to help!

Comment: @RitikKumar you should accept an answer which worked for you the best.